# How to have custom String method in Protocol Buffer?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

Let's say I have a proto file like:

```
message Sample {
  Test t = 1;
}

message Test {
  string s = 1;
}
```

I want to have my own customize `String` method on type `Test`, but since the auto generated code of `protoc` already includes `String` method, my custom `String` method leads to a compiler error.

It is worth mentioning the auto generated `String` method is:

```
func (x *Test) String() string {
    return protoimpl.X.MessageStringOf(x)
}
```

The above code, just prints the value itself but I was wondering if there is any way which I can use my custom `String` implementation?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you should mess around with generated `pb` files and use a wrapper struct instead.

```
type Wrapper struct{
   pb.Sample
}

func (w Wrapper) String() string{
  ...
}
```

Second option that comes to my mind is that maybe you can write a plugin for protoc and make it use those methods when needed struct tag is given.

Comment: Nobody should mess around in `.pb.go` files. The very first line of each and every one of those files reads: _"// Code generated by protoc-gen-go. DO NOT EDIT."_ for good reason

Answer (score -2):

You can replace the implementation in the `*.pb.go` file itself.
However, the change will be gone if the original proto file is compiled at the same path where the modified file is.

Comment: True, but after each compile it is gone

Comment: And you'd be ignoring what it says on every generated file on line 1: _"// Code generated by protoc-gen-go. DO NOT EDIT."_

Never edit generated files, especially for things like protobuf: use wrappers, implement your own marshaller or whatever, but don't mess with the types themselves.